# Data from Api not showing kotlin

Tags: firebase, api, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I create retrofitconfig for get data from API in first time I use it works and good but in 2 days data not showing from Api

this is my interface

```
interface CnnApi {
@GET("cnbc-news/")
fun getNewsCNN(): Call<NewsResponse>

@GET("cnbc-news/{type}")
fun getNewsCCNType(@Path("type") type: String ) : Call<NewsResponse>
```

}

and then this is object I use to make retrofit

```
object RetrofitConfig {
fun getData(): CnnApi {
    val loggingInterceptor =
        HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .build()
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl("https://berita-indo-api.vercel.app/v1/")
        .client(client)
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(CnnApi::class.java)
}
```

}

and then this is my HomeViewModel

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val _isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isLoading: LiveData<Boolean> = _isLoading

private val _dataItem = MutableLiveData<List<DataItem>>()
val dataItem: LiveData<List<DataItem>> = _dataItem

private val _image = MutableLiveData<Image>()
val image:LiveData<Image> = _image

companion object{
    private const val TAG = "News"
    private const val type ="lifestyle"
}

init{
    getDataFromAPI()
}


private fun getDataFromAPI(){
    EspressoIdlingResource.increment()
    _isLoading.value = true
    val client = RetrofitConfig.getData().getNewsCCNType(type)
    client.enqueue(object: Callback<NewsResponse>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<NewsResponse>, response: Response<NewsResponse>) {
            _isLoading.value = false
            if(response.isSuccessful || response.body()?.total== 200){
                _dataItem.value = response.body()?.data
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG,"onFailure: ${response.message()}")
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            _isLoading.value = false
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${t.message.toString()}")
            EspressoIdlingResource.decrement()
        }
    })

}
```

}

This is the view or how I show the data

```
 homeViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
    _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root

        homeViewModel.dataItem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { news ->
            binding.articleTitle.text = news[0].title
            Glide.with(this)
                .load(news[0].image.small)
                .into(binding.articleImage)
            binding.articleFrom.text = "CNN Indonesia"
            link = news[0].link
        })

        binding.imageCard.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.data = Uri.parse(link)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Logcat or error
[image]
logcat is what I think makes the application so it doesn't display the desired data, how to solve must-revalidate data ? because I think because of it I cant show the data from API

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as images.

Comment: So I see 200 code with an OK result. So it means that you get the data but don't display it. Have you somehow to add it to your views?

Comment: same as mine the result is Ok but the data not showing,  i added Code for display the data. in first try I use it, it showing. but after 2 days the data not showing and in logcat showing must-revalidate.

Comment: If you try to log those values, do you get the correct output?

Comment: you can see in last picture the data log is showing normal but in apps data not showing